# Smooth transitions between pages - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to add smooth transitions between all pages. I used ReactCSSTransitionGroup and wrap the main layout. Just like this

```
class MainLayout extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <TopNav />
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="example"
            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
            transitionAppear={true}
            transitionAppearTimeout={500}
          >
          {/* Content */}
          { this.props.content }
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        <BottomNav />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my route configuration.

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { mount } from 'react-mounter';
    import MainLayout from './layouts/MainLayout.jsx';
    import Home from './home/Home.jsx';

FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  action () {
    mount(MainLayout, { content: (<Home />) });
    setTitle();
  },
});
```

Now it's working fine when the first load.  But transition doesn't work while navigate to other pages. How can I solve that?

Comment: Can you share your route configuration?

Comment: @GiladArtzi I'm using meteor and flow router. Description updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render the children by cloning it and giving it a key, like this

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    key: this.props.location.pathname
})}
```

According to the [example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/animations/app.js) component from react-router

Comment: So that ReactCSSTransitionGroup will be able to do the transition instead of directly switching between pages

Comment: Gave unique keys to the child elements using node-uuid package. You make my day! Thanks